# how to set P4COMMANDCHARSET value while P4CHARSET is value of utf16?

Tags: perforce

Trying to use p4.exe command line to manipulate perforce. Because the server uses unicode so at first I changed the P4CHARSET value to utf16le-bom(p4 set P4CHARSET=utf16le-bom). Later I try the command 'p4 login' the console returned 'p4 can't support a wide charset unless P4COMMANDCHARSET is set to another charset.'. After reading the guidance from the page ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r08.2/doc/user/i18nnotes.txt I know when the P4CHARSET is set to utf16 or 32 the P4COMMANDCHARSET has to be set to something else so it can read the command line command. But every time I used the command 'p4 set P4COMMANDCHARSET=winansi' it still return the same error info said that it can't support the wide charset. Now even the 'p4 help' command is not working, can anyone help me with this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing the command charset:

`p4 -Q winansi login`

If that works it just means that you haven't set P4COMMANDCHARSET correctly in your environment.  Try running `p4 set` and see where it's reading environment data from.

And see this page for more info: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Internationalization-and-Localization#i18n

Comment: The forcing command has worked. I have found the perforce read its environment variables from 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Perforce/Environment' table in registry in windows2008R2. I modified the p4commandcharset variable's value over there and now the command line is working properly. Thank you for your answer.